# What is the purpose of _field_sql_storage_columnname()?

Tags: entities

While reviewing a patch, I came across an interesting function, [_field_sql_storage_columnname()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!field_sql_storage!field_sql_storage.module/function/_field_sql_storage_columnname/7). And I couldn't help but wondering, why on earth do we have this function?

git blame unfortunately wasn't helpful, as it only lead me to a commit that cleanup up windows line-endings.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's clear what the function is doing, the question was more why a function is required for that.

My guess is that the function was there from very first day field API existed where it might have made sense to change it. Nowadays, it's not going to be as easy as "just" changing that function, because it will obviously completely break all existing field tables.

I think the function is still useful for consistency reasons as there is one for the table name as well and I think it's also easier to read because it implies the string is the column name, which might not be that obvious if you e.g have a line like this:

```
$sql_field = "$table_alias." . _field_sql_storage_columnname($field['field_name'], $specifier['column']);
// vs.
$sql_field = "$table_alias." . $field['field_name'] . '_' . $specifier['column'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason to have a function that returns the column name is that a field could save more than one value. For example, an image field saves the following values:

- fid
- alt
- title
- width
- height

When the field data are saved in the database table, the column name must be unique, to avoid conflicts with other fields.

The reason why the fields are not saved as serialized data is to make searching for a field with specific values faster. For example, you could search for an image with a specific weight with an SQL query, rather than executing a generic query, getting the data, passing the data to `unserialize()`, and verifying the data contain what you are looking for.

The reason to have a single function that returns the column name is to make easier to change that code, if there is the need to change it: It is enough to change the code of a single function, rather than searching for the code used in the module, and changing it.